# plot() and do.call(): How to pass expressions to plot title when '...' is used otherwise?

Tags: r, plot, do.call, plotmath

When run the following code, I obtain `Error in as.graphicsAnnot(text) : could not find function "bold"`. How can I fix this?

```
my.qq <- function(x, main=expression(bold(italic(F)~~"Q-Q plot")),
                  margs=list(side=3, cex=par("cex.main"), font=par("font.main"),
                  adj=par("adj"), xpd=NA), ...)
{
    plot(qnorm(ppoints(n <- length(x))), sort(x), ...)
    do.call(mtext, c(list(main), margs))
}
x <- rnorm(100)
my.qq(x)
my.qq(x, main=substitute(bold(italic(F)[N(mu.,s2.)]~~"Q-Q plot"), list(mu.=0, s2.=1))) # fails
```

My goal is to use the list `margs` to pass additional arguments to `mtext()`. That's normally done with `...`, but those arguments are already passed to `plot()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`substitute` in this case returns an language object, not an expression. the expression `expression` is used loosely in `R`, however here it appears that `mtext` needs an object of class `expression`.

You can ensure this by wrapping `substitute(...)` in `as.expression()`

```
my.qq(x, main=as.expression(substitute(bold(italic(F)[N(mu.,s2.)]~~"Q-Q plot"), list(mu.=0, s2.=1))))
```

or more simply by passing an expression to substitute (as would be required in a normal call to `mtext`)

```
my.qq(x, main=substitute(expression(bold(italic(F)[N(mu.,s2.)]~~"Q-Q plot")), list(mu.=0, s2.=1)))
```

Both the examples above will produce
[image]

There is a note in the help for `substitute`

> Substituting and quoting often cause confusion when the argument is expression(...). The result is a call to the expression constructor function and needs to be evaluated with eval to give the actual expression object.

however in this case `eval` is not required

Comment: *Argh*, I should have known that ... Thanks a lot for helping (so quickly)!