# How to combine do.call() plot() and expression()

Tags: r, plot, expression, do.call

I am getting an error when I try and combine using `expression` with `do.call` and `plot`.

```
 x <- 1:10
 y <- x^1.5
```

I can get the plot I want by using only the `plot` function:

```
plot(y~x,xlab=expression(paste("Concentration (",mu,"M)")))
```

However, I would like to implement my plot using `do.call`. I have a really long list of parameters stored as a list, `p`. However, when I try and pass the list to `do.call` I get the following error:

```
p <- list(xlab=expression(paste("Concentration (",mu,"M)")))
do.call(plot,c(y~x,p))
Error in paste("Concentration (", mu, "M)") : 
  object 'mu' not found
```

I also tried defining the formula explicitly in the args passed to `do.call`. ie. `do.call(plot,c(formula=y~x,p))`. I do not understand why I am getting the error - especially because the following does not give an error:

```
do.call(plot,c(0,p))
```

(and gives the desired mu character in the xaxis).

Comment: +1 for your interesting observation about the behavior of `do.call(plot,c(0,p))`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [plot() and do.call(): How to pass expressions to plot title when '...' is used otherwise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982856/plot-and-do-call-how-to-pass-expressions-to-plot-title-when-is-used-o)

Comment: @Metrics I did read that question before posting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`do.call` evaluates the parameters before running the function; try wrapping the expression in `quote`:

```
p <- list(xlab=quote(expression(paste("Concentration (",mu,"M)"))))
do.call("plot", c(y~x, p))
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why `do.call(plot,c(0,p))` does not give an error?

Comment: Interesting find! Looks like my guess why it didn't work wasn't quite correct.  One is using `graphics:::plot.default` and the other is using `graphics:::plot.formula`. I see that `graphics:::plot.formula` is doing some funky stuff with the `xlab` parameter using `enquote`; I'd have to look closer to understand why that causes it to fail.

Comment: You should both stop using `sep` arguments in plotmath-`paste`. At best they are ignored, and at worst they get put at the end of the expression and not where you wanted them.

Comment: Nice catch @Dwin, `sep` removed.

Comment: @DWin I also removed the `sep`. **BUT** I do not understand why it does not place the default space into the expression without the `sep` argument.

Comment: What "default space"? Spaces do not get interpreted as anything in R expressions.

Comment: Look at the documentation on `?plotmath`. There is no `sep` argument to that function. Try putting in sep="+" and see what happens.

Comment: @dayne Basically, as @DWin is pointing out, when it's inside of an `expression` object being interpreted by plotmath, `paste` does not refer at all to the familiar `base::paste`. Might be easier to grok this if you compare with something like `x[i]` which also has a very different meaning inside and outside of a plotmath call.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `alist` rather then `list`

```
p <- alist(xlab=expression(paste("Concentration (",mu,"M)")))
do.call(plot,c(y~x,p))
```

Answer (score 7):

Setting `quote=TRUE` also works. It in effect prevents `do.call()` from evaluating the elements of `args` before it passes them to the function given by `what`.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x^1.5
p <- list(xlab=expression(paste("Concentration (",mu,"M)",sep="")))

do.call(what = "plot", args = c(y ~ x, p), quote = TRUE)
```