# Shiny: use do.call to run render-family functions

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use `do.call` to run **render** family functions, like `renderPrint()`. Below code doesn't work:

```
rm(list=ls())

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
              choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
              selected = 1),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$value <- do.call("renderPrint", list({ input$select }))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Error:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    45: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    44: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
    43: $.reactivevalues
[...]
```

How to achieve this? I am guessing that this is somehow connected with environment and lazy evaluation, so closure might the solution, but this is only guessing...

Comment: I suspect `observe({ output$value <- do.call("renderPrint", list({ input$select })) }) would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to archieve this based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18281015/4357017) from SO. The key part is using `alist` instead of `list`. From the documentation:

> **alist** handles its arguments as if they described function arguments. So the values are *not evaluated*, and tagged arguments with no value are allowed whereas list simply ignores them. alist is most often used in conjunction with formals.

```
rm(list=ls())

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(    
  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
              choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
              selected = 1),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {          
  output$value <- do.call(
    renderPrint, 
    alist(input$select)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Alternatively, you can probably use the `quoted` argument in `renderPrint` and wrap `quote` around your expressions, but I had no luck with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

note: I was trying to add on to Gregor's answer in a comment but kind of failed.. read his first!

`do.call` evaluates its arguments by default when it constructs the call.

But you can specify `quote = TRUE` to leave the args unevaluated:

```
output$value <- do.call(renderPrint, list(quote(input$select), quoted = TRUE), quote = TRUE)
```

But simpler would be to just use a quoted arg with the call:

```
output$value <- do.call(renderPrint, list(quote(input$select)))
```

Then the quoted expression gets evaluated at the time of the call, and you won't be evaluating `input$select` outside a reactive context.

Comment: `alist` does a trick and it is simpler modification than `quote`, but thx for answer.

Comment: Very interesting. I was actually playing around with `quote` quite a bit and couldn't make it work. Seeing that it is so straightforward makes me fell a little dumb :)