# How to define multiple shiny output elements in a map or apply?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create `tabPanel` elements for each data frame in a list.  This seems like it should be possible with `do.call` and `map` functions, but it produces an error.

"Error in [[: attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex"

I found this question which seems relevant, and I tried to wrap all my list arguments in `alist()`, but this didn't work either.
[Shiny: use do.call to run render-family functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676272/shiny-use-do-call-to-run-render-family-functions/46677016#46677016)

Here is a minimal reprex.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("tabs")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dat <- lst(iris, mtcars)
  
  if (FALSE) {
    # this works, but would like to replicate with do.call and map
    output$tabs <- renderUI(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("iris", renderDataTable(dat$iris)),
        tabPanel("mtcars", renderDataTable(dat$mtcars)),
      )
    )

  } else {
    # doesn't work
    output$tabs <- renderUI(
      do.call(
        tabsetPanel,
        map2(names(dat), map(dat, renderDataTable), tabPanel)
      )
    )
  }
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the inner `map` to create the renderDataTable. It seems like when it goes to render the data, it can't find it anymore. This looks like it happens because `renderDataTable` stores the data value as an unevaluated expression rather than storing the data itself. The documentation says it takes "an expression that returns a data frame or a matrix" rather than the data itself which is being passed along in the `map()`. One possible work around is this

```
output$tabs <- renderUI(
  do.call(
    tabsetPanel,
    map(names(dat), function(x) tabPanel(x, renderDataTable(dat[[x]])))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're importing `tidyverse` it may slightly increase readability to use the `rlang` [splice operator](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html) (`!!!`):

> The splice operator `!!!` implemented in dynamic dots injects a list of arguments into a function call. It belongs to the family of injection operators and provides the same functionality as `do.call()`.

```r
output$tabs <- renderUI(
    tabsetPanel(
        !!!unname(
            imap(dat, \(df, df_name) tabPanel(df_name, renderDataTable(df)))
        )
    )
)
```

Annoyingly you need to `unname()` your list or your app will display:

> Error: Tabs should all be unnamed arguments, but some are named: iris, mtcars

I am not sure why an unnamed list is required.

However, I can't imagine many `shiny` apps where it is a good idea to import the entire `tidyverse`. I suspect generally I would prefer MrFlick's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77274191/12545041).